# INSERT IF NOT EXISTS ELSE RETURN THE VALUE

Tags: sqlite

I need an SQLite query which inserts a value into some table if not exist, and return the value if exist. So far I've found "insert if not exists" part here as:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (str1, str2, date)
SELECT 'example','someText', DATETIME()
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableName WHERE str1 = 'example')
```

I'm new at SQLite but I need something like:

```
IF NOT EXIST: INSERT the value
ELSE (IF EXIST): RETURN the value
```

Can somebody tell me how to do this please? Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just run this as two separate statements, first try to grab the existing value, if you get no rows in return, do the insert?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Well I will be using this inside some C++ application with "sqlite3.h" and I'm not sure if I can catch the correct results (like is exist) if I use two separate statemens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my understanding,  SQLite doesn't support this. But in the future it will support this.

See: [https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_returning.html#:~:text=The%20RETURNING%20clause%20is%20designed%20to%20provide%20the,report%20the%20chosen%20values%20back%20to%20the%20application](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_returning.html#:%7E:text=The%20RETURNING%20clause%20is%20designed%20to%20provide%20the,report%20the%20chosen%20values%20back%20to%20the%20application).

It's in a draft to be implemented.

The possible SQL could be:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (str1, str2, date)
SELECT 'example','someText', DATETIME()
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableName WHERE str1 = 'example') RETURNING *;
```